# Noise and Outliers in DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, outliers, definition, noise, dbscan

Why are **noise** and **outliers** treated as the same concept in **DBSCAN** (*density-based spatial clustering of applications with noise*)?

Comment: It does not really "treat" either. They are *ignored*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBSCAN treats everything that cannot be assigned to a cluster under the parameterization given separately. Clusters are *signal* for clustering algorithms. Everything that is not signal is by definition *noise*, so everything that DBSCAN cannot cluster is labeled "noise". This applies equally to outliers (points that are so far away from *all* clusters they cannot be clustered) and to "inlier" (points that lie *between* clusters, but far away from every one, and therefore cannot be assigned confidently to any one cluster).